# Open sample document from bundle

Tags: macos, cocoa, bundle, nsdocument

I would like my OS X app to open a sample document located in the application bundle.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tutorial.doc" ofType:nil];
[_documentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] display:YES completionHandler:nil];
```

This works but has an unexpected effect: if I make changes to the document and save, the next time I open the bundle document the changes persist. I expected the bundle document to be read-only.

What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent this sample document to be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`duplicateDocumentWithContentsOfURL:copying:displayName:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocumentController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method instead. This creates a copy of the document the user can play with (and save to some other location if he wants to). This method is available only on OS X 10.7 or later though.

Comment: This is useful but I would prefer to avoid making a copy of the document, mostly because when the user closes the document he's prompted to save the copy. Isn't there a way to say, "don't save this document"?